# Chartjs - legends take up too much space on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, angular-chart

Good day everybody,

I have a graph with four legends, all of which are longer. How can I display the graph below large enough and still display the legends above?

[image]

if i hide the legends, the graph looks good, of course.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make use of an html legend, see this example in the chart.js documentation on how to implement it: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/legend/html.html

Comment: Thanks. I will create my own legends :D